No more Sentinel-2 data available on GEE from February 7th, 2024
I want to analyze Sentinel-2 data from January to the present, but the data is only accessible until February 7th, 2024. Here's an example of the GEE code for visualizing Sentinel-2 data in RGB, which only functions until that date. Does anyone know what's happening or how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance for your help.
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterDate('2024-03-01', '2024-03-30')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

Map.setCenter(83.277, 17.7009, 12);

Map.addLayer(dataset.mean(), visualization, 'RGB');

      

I tried with former collections but it didn't work too.

It seems that the data are there, but cloud masking routine and/or image scaling has been changed. Try to comment cloud masking and change value range in the palette to see the image
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterDate('2024-04-20', '2024-05-30')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
                  // .map(maskS2clouds)
                  ;

var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 5000,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

Map.setCenter(83.277, 17.7009, 12);

Map.addLayer(dataset.mean(), visualization, 'RGB');


I have also encountered this issue, and can second Oleh's note that something has changed about cloud masking on GEE. If anyone has insight on what has happened I would be eager to learn more.

Your posting should be a comment to the question, not an answer. Please consider changing that.

Hi Antares. I wasn't able to leave a comment because I don't have enough reputation yet. I realize this was less than ideal. Can change it when I do.

Hi Afrothunder, thanks for reporting back! I didn't know about that limit needed to comment... Your answer popped up in the review-queue. StackOverflow should really overthink their rep policy towards new posts/users...

At this day, on repository 'COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED' and cloud Mask with 'QA60' it's working.
But, if you are working 'COPERNICUS/S2_SR' and cloud mask after february, does't work with 'QA60', you need to work with a new property 'MSK_CLDPRB'.
But this 'MSK_CLDPRB' work's with probability (0-100) and 'QA60'  works with bitwase.
Check this example:
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('MSK_CLDPRB');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  // var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
  //     .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  var mask = qa.lte(20)
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2024-06-01', '2024-06-30')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  //.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

var visualization = {
  min: 0.1,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

// Map.setCenter(83.277, 17.7009, 12);
print(dataset.first())

Map.addLayer(dataset.median(), visualization, 'RGB');

